# storageclass reclaimPolicy vs pv reclaimPolicy

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, storage-class-specifier

I wanted to know what's the difference of the `reclaimPolicy` in `StorageClass` vs. `PersistentVolume`.

Currently we created multiple `PersistentVolume` with a `StorageClass` that has a `reclaimPolicy` of `Delete`, however we changed the `PersistentVolume`'s `reclaimPolicy` manually via `kubectl patch pv PV_NAME -p '{"spec":{"persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy":"Retain"}}'` to have a `Retain` value.

what will happen now if I try to delete the `StorageClass` or even the cluster or accidentily remove `pvc`' s does the value of the `StorageClass` has any effect on the `pv` even after creating?

Answer (score 5):

> I wanted to know what's the difference of the reclaimPolicy in StorageClass vs. PersistentVolume.

They mean the same thing, the difference is that the one in `StorageClass` is used for [dynamic provisioning of volumes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/dynamic-provisioning/), for manually created persistent volumes they use the `reclaimPolicy` they were assigned during creation.

> what will happen now if I try to delete the StorageClass or even the cluster or accidentily remove pvc' s does the value of the StorageClass has any effect on the pv even after creating?

I don't think anything will happen if you delete `StorageClass`, no pv or pvc should be deleted. If you delete a PVC then the `reclaimPolicy` of the `PersistentVolume` will be used.